# RoR "Has many" link > How to get title via foreign key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-key-relationship, has-many

I have a basic question of relationship in RoR :

In a view, I try to display the title of a group, which is in the table "groups", and only the key "group_id" is stored in the table/object "product".

When I write product.group_id, I see the value in the database, but if I write product.group.title, RoR tolds me undefined method `group' for #.

This is a basic question so I appreciate your help !

The code in the view (this works but is so awful ! I'm sure there is a way like product.group.title)

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <%= Group.find(product.group_id).title %>  </td>
<% end %>
```

and the models :

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :groups
  has_and_belongs_to_many :authors
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be `belongs_to :group` not `groups`

Also, in your view, you could more easily do this:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <%= product.group.title %>  </td>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you for anwser.. but it doesn't work. When I write product.group_id, I see the value in the database, but if I write product.group.title, RoR tolds me undefined method `group' for #.

Comment: This is the precise error I have : NoMethodError in Products#index

Showing /home/stephane/www/site2/app/views/products/index.html.erb where line #16 raised:

undefined method `group' for #<Product:0x000000032f3160>

Comment: Yes, product.authors works. I see the to_string version of the authors objects... but it seems I missed something to link to group ?

Comment: And you changed this part right? `belongs_to :group`. If so, then the only thing I can think of is to try not using the word "group": `belongs_to :mygroup, :class_name => "Group", :foreign_key => "group_id"` Then go `product.mygroup`. Also try restarting rails.

Comment: You fixed it with your first sentence ! :-) It is belongs_to :group in the singular form and NOT the plural. I never understand why they play with singular or plural forms in RoR (why not always the same word ?) but the error was that I wrote belgons_to :groups with an "S", which was not working. removing the "S" solves the problem and I can access to product.group.title now. Thanks !